# Remember position of equal sign from one align environment to the next

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, align

As you know, the align-environment puts all positions marked with & (normally the equals sign) exactly beneath each other. I now want to save the position LaTeX calculates for & and use it again later. In more detail, I have something like that:

```
\begin{xyz}
  \begin{align}
    x &= a \\
      &= b   %store the position of & in \positionequal
  \end{align}
\end{xyz}
\begin{xyz}
   \begin{align} %read \positionequal and use it to put & at the right position
      &= c
   \end{align}
\end{xyz}
```

The things marked with % are unclear to me:

How to I find out this position, save it (so that it does not get lost from one xyz-environment to the next) and the use it again?

Comment: If stuff in the second align is wider than in the first, do you want it to feedback and make the first one adjust its alignment?

Comment: Of course, that would be brilliant, but I would be satisfied without this extra feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not the nicest thing to do, it seems possible to solve my problem by using `\pdfsavepos` or the `zref` package.

It gives you access to the distance between the beginning and end of the Lefthand side of your equation, so that you can reproduce this distance by an appropriate `\hspace` later.

Answer (score 4):

use `\phantom{...}` with the widest element from the earlier environment, i.e., the one that causes `align` to calculate the position.  in your example,

```
\begin{xyz}
  \begin{align}
    x &= a \\
      &= b   %store the position of & in \positionequal
  \end{align}
\end{xyz}
\begin{xyz}
   \begin{align} %read \positionequal and use it to put & at the right position
      \phantom{x} &= c
   \end{align}
\end{xyz}
```

Comment: This is a good idea and should do the job. Nevertheless, I was hoping for something more "automatic", since (for some complicated reason) I am faced with a situation like above a lot of times, and the solution above makes me "guess" the longest element of every {align}.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\intertext` for the text between evironments, that way you will have all the `&` marks aligned in the same position. See e.g. [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-mathstext); they say it is only for short text, but IIRC I was able to stuff long stretches of text and sectioning commands in there without issues (YMMV).

Comment: This is not what I intended to do. As you see, my two align-environments are in _different_ environments (which I just called xyz), so I cannot use the \intertext-command.

Comment: @JF Meier: sorry, I overlooked that. If you are the author of xyz environment, you could avoid the nesting problem by split its beginning and end into stand-along commands like `\startxyz\begin{align}...&=...\intertext{\stopxyz ... \startxyz} ... &= ...\end{align}\stopxyz`, or use `\beginxyz...\endxyz`.

Comment: Although I am the author of the xyz-environment, it uses a "true" environment (namely preview from the preview-package) which cannot be avoided. Imagine that xyz is something like a minipage.