# Align all equal signs in the document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

Is there a way to align all the equal signs in all equations all over the document? I write a theses (`scrbook`) and like all equal signs to line up. At least in a chapter if not possible for the whole document.

The `\begin{align}` or `\begin{eqnarray}` just do that for the small group. And to use `\intertext` for a whole chapter is unpractikal.

Example how it is at the moment:

```
\begin{align}    
F_L^{\rightarrow}   & =     q ( E_{eFeld}^{\rightarrow} + v^{\rightarrow} \times B^{\rightarrow} )
    \end{align}

much text

    \begin{align}
    F_{Lx}  & =     q ( E_{eFeld} + v_{gx} * B )
    \end{align}

    little text

    \begin{align}
    T   & =     F_{L1} - F_{L2}                                         \\
        & =     q ( E_{eFeld} + v_{g1} * B - E_{eFeld} - v_{g2} * B )   \\
        & =     q*B ( v_{g1} - v_{g2} )         
    \end{align}                     

    \subsection{new subsection}

    very little text

    \begin{align}
    P_{Photon}  & =     hf * nAc                \\
                & =     \frac{E_{Photon}}{t}    
    \end{align}

    more text

    \begin{align}
    F_{0}       & =     2nhfA               \\
                & =     \frac{2 P_{Photon}}{c}  
    \end{align}
```

And I would like to have something like:

```
A  = b+C

Text

A  = longe equation

**New Headline**

B  = also nice equation
```

And so on. I guess you get what I want. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: This does not sound like a good idea; one equation with a long left-hand side will force all the others to be indented.  Perhaps you would prefer to be using the `fleqn` option, that sets all equations with a fixed indent from the left margin, rather than centered.

Comment: I tried fleqn. It looks not good. If there are sutch unplesant left-hand equations I guess there it a way to exclude them from the alignment like it is with the numbering.

Comment: But if you insist upon it, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115534/align-separate-equations/115549#115549 where I created the `algneqn` environment

Comment: Thanks. Now I have the problem that the algneqn changes the sice of the \frac{}{}. It becomes pushed together to fit on a line. Can you help with that. (I tried to chance the definition of algneqn from equation to align and equnarry what both created errors)

Comment: unrelated to question but don't do `P_{Photon}` math italic is designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word. use `P_{\mathrm{Photon}}` or `P_{\mathit{Photon}}`

Comment: Thanks for the P_{\mathit{}}. Looks mutch better. Has anybody a solution for the \frac{}{} Problem that it is nicely big again.

Comment: @Göran  Sorry  I did not get your message to me (you needed to say `@Steven Segletes` in order for me to be alerted).  To fix a `\frac` displaying in `\textstyle`, you have two choices: 1) Add the macro `\displaystyle` prior to the `\frac`, or else, put `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble and then use `\dfrac`, which is short for `\displaystyle\frac`.

Comment: Probably same question as [horizontal alignment - Remember position of equal sign from one align environment to the next - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28023/remember-position-of-equal-sign-from-one-align-environment-to-the-next).

Answer (score 3):

Starting with my answer on [align separate equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115534/align-separate-equations/115549#115549), I found I needed to change a few things, specifically because the OP for this question wanted to include multiline equations.  As such, I had to reinstate `\arraystretch` to a non-zero value (in fact, I set it to 1.2).  But with that, I had to do some `\vspace` manipulations going into and out of the `algneqn` environment I created.

But in the end, all the equal signs are aligned, per the OP's request.  Setting the values of `\leftalgn` and `\rightalgn` will determine where on the overall line the alignment tab will be set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\leftalgn{0.3}\def\rightalgn{0.6}
\def\algnrow{\rule{\leftalgn\textwidth}{0ex}&\rule{\rightalgn\textwidth}{0ex}}
% CONSTRAINTS:
% equation label must fit in {1 -\leftalgn -\rightalgn}\textwidth
% \leftalgn must be larger than any text to left of align character
% \rightalgn must be larger than any text to right of align character
\newenvironment{algneqn}{%
  \vspace{-1.6\baselineskip}%
  \arraycolsep=0ex\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \begin{equation}%
  \begin{array}{rl}%
  \algnrow\\%
}%
 {\\\algnrow%
  \end{array}\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend%
}
\def\snug#1{\vspace*{-#1\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{algneqn}    
F_L^{\rightarrow}   & =     q ( E_{eFeld}^{\rightarrow} + v^{\rightarrow} \times B^{\rightarrow} )
    \end{algneqn}

much text

    \begin{algneqn}
    F_{Lx}  & =     q ( E_{eFeld} + v_{gx} * B )
    \end{algneqn}

    little text

    \begin{algneqn}
    T   & =     F_{L1} - F_{L2}                                         \\
        & =     q ( E_{eFeld} + v_{g1} * B - E_{eFeld} - v_{g2} * B )   \\
        & =     q*B ( v_{g1} - v_{g2} )         
    \end{algneqn}                     

    \subsection{new subsection}

    very little text

    \begin{algneqn}
    P_{Photon}  & =     hf * nAc                \\
                & =     \dfrac{E_{Photon}}{t}    
    \end{algneqn}

    more text

    \begin{algneqn}
    F_{0}       & =     2nhfA               \\
                & =     \dfrac{2 P_{Photon}}{c}  
    \end{algneqn}
\end{document}
```

[image]